# Piezoelectricity from high pressure

Tags: electromagnetism, pressure, energy-conservation, work, piezoelectric

Is it possible to convert 10Mp vapor or hydraulic pressure to electricity using piezo crystals? What would be the energy output in watts or the theoretical maximum conversion efficiency?

Comment: Piezos, while nice for measuring deflections and making sparks to light stoves, are not high power devices. Propose a cyclic loading method, and then you can calculate the energy output per cycle (note that you can't extract piezo-power from a static pressure).

Comment: For the sake of the argument, let's say the pressure would be introduced dynamically by a small explosion that would create the 10mp pressure in 1 cubic meter container every minute. The walls of the container would be covered with 1cm thick piezo material e.g. quartz. How many kwh could we get theoretically? How would one calculate it?

Comment: For the sake of argument you should consider using an internal combustion engine. That will actually work and there are some that can achieve around 50% efficiency, even though small engines will be around 15-30%. The performance of these engines is limited by thermodynamics, piezo-elements can't change anything about that.